# PHP CLI как получить домен

Tags: php, docker, консоль

Есть `PHP` процесс который работает в месте с веб-сервером внутри контейнера `Docker`, процесс запускается с помощью `PHP-CLI` и после работы должен отдавать пару ссылок типа `доменХостМашины\ссылка`, как мне из моего процесса получить домен хост машины?

В крайнем случае можно подставлять `IP` хост машины, но как его получить с `PHP-CLI` я тоже не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, `php-cli` ничего не знает про веб-сервер и его окружение, поэтому домен получить не удастся.

Самый простой способ получить внешний IP, не завязываясь на окружение — это получить адрес у внешнего сервиса, например, http://checkip.dyndns.com/:

```
$externalContent = file_get_contents('http://checkip.dyndns.com/');
preg_match('/Current IP Address: \[?([:.0-9a-fA-F]+)\]?/', $externalContent, $m);
$externalIp = $m[1];
```

Как опция — можно использовать переменную окружения в `docker`, через которую в скрипт будет передаваться домен или ip.

Comment: Пока что сделаю этот ответ верным, если поступят более исчерпывающие на мой взгляд ответы, я сделаю их решающими мою проблему. Благодарю!

Comment: скажите, под опцией, что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Опция — имеется в виду что это альтернативный путь